# Where to store the BigCommerce access token and other data

Tags: laravel, redis, storage, access-token, bigcommerce

I am using laravel to build an app in BigCommerce. I am able to get access token but I need to store that for future requests. What is the best possible way to store the app data for BigCommerce?

Answer (score 2):

I've got this working by creating a DB schema in Laravel where in there are tables like stores, users, app_settings.

Whenever the user installs an app, I am storing an access token and other information like store hash in stores table and user details in users table.

Whenever the app is loaded I could get the store and user information via verify signed request payload. Using this I am able to configure my app settings for the user and store those in app settings table.

So when I create a Webhook for the store, I could get the store hash from response as producer key and accordingly I can find the access token for the store using store hash in stores table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're git ignoring your config.json or .env files, you could store these there. However after speaking with one of our Developer Advocates, I wanted to pass along some best practice advice. :) You may want to consider using a secrets manager for option #1 in your decision here. A secrets manager meaning a tool to safely store these variables like Secrets in Github or Key Vault in Azure.

Also, this resource may be helpful to review for your use case. https://www.codementor.io/@ccornutt/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-kvcbrk55z